# Disable Modal Dialogs from XSLTListView

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, modal-dialog

i need to disable some modal dialogs for the form display in a listview.
At the list settings I have disabled the modal dialog (NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE").

For the items of the list it works fine. But the groupings still opens the modal dialog. I need to disable this too..

The second modal dialog occurs on the "home page" of the site definition. At the onet.xml I have implemented two XsltListViews. They still open the modal dialog. Can I implement the NavigateFor... attribute there too?

Best Regards

Comment: OT: Please keep in mind to mark answers that helped you to solve your questions.

Comment: Shegit: For sure I will do :) But therefore I need a correct answer :D